# What is decentralized internet?

Tags: internet, network

I have to do a college project on `decentralized internet`. I have tried searching on google and Wikipedia but not found any proper article (not "properly explained" to me at least). Can anyone give me some idea about how does it work and its usability in future?

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for resources.

Comment: The answers below are good but would add that the assigned topic might be looking for something like TOR, where name services and setup of connectivity are much more fuly decentralized (and, obviously, anonymized to some degree).

Comment: indeed, @rnxrx...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The public Internet *is* decentralized. It is simply the ISPs connecting to each other in whatever way each decides and negotiates with its peers. ISPs decide to which other ISPs they want to connect, and they negotiate the connections. Some ISPs will offer services that let other ISPs connect to each other, and there are some inter-connection points where a bunch of ISPs will connect to each other, but there is no central authority dictating how ISPs connect to other ISPs.

There are some generally accepted practices that ISPs use. For example, the routing protocol of the Internet is BGP. That doesn't mean that an ISP cannot reach an agreement with another ISP to use a different routing protocol between the two, but in general, ISPs need to use BGP with other ISPs, which is by general ISP consensus.

Comment: Just to add: while the Internet itself is decentralized, there are central services / institutions for e.g. handling the address space and DNS domain names (IANA). However, these services are also somehat decentralized as large parts of the address space and top level domains are delegated to regional institutions (ARIN, RIPE, ...) who then sell them to ISPs (roughly).

Comment: Of course, those centralized services are followed by consensus. There is nothing to prevent an ISP from deciding to use something else, other than being shunned by other ISPs. There is nothing like a law that requires an ISP to follow any of the standards, and some standards are not followed by some ISPs (e.g. RFC 3021), but most ISPs will not peer with an ISP that doesn't follow the general ISP consensus. Even the IETF doesn't vote for RFCs, they operate by consensus.