# Is there any decentralized network of any kind in actual use?

Tags: internet

I've spent a lot of time trying everything I've ever found which is decentralized. Every single such network has always been a ghost town; a complete waste of time, pointless to attempt to use with nobody using it.

Has this finally changed now? I can't help but feel as if I'm missing out on a whole new world of decentralization.

I'm not looking for:

1. Dead/ghost town projects.
2. Vaporware which cannot actually be used except "in the future".
3. Centralized projects which *claim* to be decentralized but actually just have a clearnet website which you have to use and a registration with Google reCAPTCHA on it.

I highly suspect that there simply is no such thing. It seems like nobody is even *trying* anymore.

Comment: There are a coupe of questions with answers here about that. For example, [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/28135/8499) and [this one](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/43009/8499).

Answer (score 3):

The Internet is the prime example for a decentralized network and has likely supplanted most other designs.

There are bodies controlling or coordinating some aspects of the Internet to allow interoperability, but the network itself is completely decentralized.