# What is hiearchy of IP addresses?

Tags: ip, ipv4, ipv6, ip-address

What is structure/hiearchy of IP addresses?

I mean, is mandatory that IP address e.g. 216.9.10.0 is subnet of 216.9.0.0? Of course many times that is the case and IMO it would be logical, but I have heard that you can own IP address space. I think only way that can work is there is now structure like this and 216.9.10.0 can be under e.g. 216.9.9.0.

That bring another questions, how routing works? Of course regardless those exections usually routers can route hiearchy piece by piece starting from first number of the IP addr to last one, but not always. Is that the case? Normally routing is hiearchy process, but few of hops are with execptions. Autonomous systems need tell with BGB that there is hiearchy address space, but remember one execption inside that space. For example, space 216.1.0.0-216.1.255.255 and somepoint inside is IP 210.1.1.1.

Comment: "_I mean, is mandatory that IP address e.g. 216.9.10.0 is subnet of 216.9.0.0?_" That depends on the network mask. All IPv4 network are subnets of `0.0.0.0/0`, but not of `0.0.0.0/8`.

Comment: "_I have heard that you can own IP address space._" No, IANA owns the IP address space and can assign it out to the RIRs, which in turn can assign it to companies, but IANA still owns it and can revoke the assignment, as can the RIRs.

Comment: Depends of network mask? With what mask 216.9.10.0 isn't subnet of 216.9.0.0? And the point of question is, can hiearchy of IP addresses be "broken"? E.g. 108.1.0.1/24 is subnet of 210.0.0.1/24? Technically routers could route this if many route mark this execption to their routering records, right?

Comment: Yeah, nobody can't "own IP", but IANA/RIRs can assign IPs to you. Now, what says location/position of IP space to you? If you at first want to use your IPs in NYC and then move London, what happens?

Comment: "_E.g. 108.1.0.1/24 is subnet of 210.0.0.1/24?_" No. "_With what mask 216.9.10.0 isn't subnet of 216.9.0.0?_" Any mask on `216.9.0.0` that is longer than `/20` will not include `216.9.10.0`. "_If you at first want to use your IPs in NYC and then move London, what happens?_" That depends on the other companies to which you want to connect. You may be able to make a business agreement to have them route any addresses you are assigned. The Internet is just agreements between connecting companies.

Comment: See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/43309/8499) and [this question and answers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/71005/8499) about the lack of hierarchy in the Internet addressing.

Comment: Please, reopen this. This theard is for wondering what in IP addresses are hiearchy and what not. @Zac67 suggest delegation is hierachy and only assinging not. Theard you linked doesn't explain this.

Comment: "That depends on the other companies to which you want to connect.......companies." This is what I asked. Is the case that sometimes parties make execption in IP hiearchy? For example, The company have own IP block, at first it use it on NYC with A&T network, then it move London and going costumer of some new ISP there. What happens IP block when? Can we configure routers to not care about hiearchy and just write manually execption "This block is under this network of this ISP, altought IP number says other."

Comment: "_Is the case that sometimes parties make execption in IP hiearchy?_" What hierarchy? Read the questions and answers I linked. It does not really exist. ISPs are just companies, and companies can connect, or not, to any other companies with which they come to peering agreements. None need to have any addressing related to the other. Companies need not peer to ISPs, they can connect to non-ISP companies.

Answer (score 1):

IP addresses are hierarchical for delegation only. You can add bits to a delegated prefix, breaking it into smaller subnets which can then be used or re-delegated.

You cannot use that information for routing however, e.g. x.0.0.0/24 and x.0.1.0/24 can be part of entirely different networks, located on different parts of the globe.

BGP is used to exchange the delegated prefixes with their respective gateways, organized within ASNs.

Comment: Okay, what do you exactly mean by "hierarchial for delegation only" What is differences between delegation on assiging? And how x.0.0.0/24 and x.0.1.0/24 can be entirely different networks if delegation only? And as inportant, what this all mean for routing?

Comment: And another question: IP addresses contain network and host part, right? So is the case that network part is "hiearchial for delegation" and host not?